Asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(nt)}{1+t^2} dt$
Question: Show that the integral
$$I(n) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(nt)}{1+t^2} dt $$
has an asymptotic expansion of the form as $n\to\infty$
$$ f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \frac{1}{n^{2k}} $$
Evaluate the coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2$.
What I've done: I've used two ways to evaluate the integral:
(1) I tried to relate to Riemann Lebesgue lemma. $I(n)$ is even in $n$, so I changed variables from $t$ to $u = t - \pi$ and then got:
$$I(n) = Re[ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\exp(-inu)\exp(-in\pi)}{1+(u+\pi)^2} dt] $$
then the function $\frac{\exp(-in\pi)}{1+(u+\pi)^2}$ is infinitely differentiable, so the integral decays like $O(n^{-k})$ for any $k\in N$, so all coefficients, after expanding the integral in the inverse powers form, must vanish.
My question: if my argument of vanishing coefficients holds, how do I show the integral do have expansion w.r.t. inverse powers of $n$? This seems arbitrary to me, especially that I don't know the coefficients $a_n$.
(2) I write $I(n) = Re[\int_0^{2\pi} (1+t^2)^{-1} e^{int} dt] =^{it = -s} = Re[\int_0^{-2\pi i} (1-s^2)^{-1} e^{-ns} i ds]$, and then show integrals of the same integrand from ${-2\pi i}$ to ${-2\pi i +2\pi}$ (call it $J_1$) and $2\pi - 2\pi i$ to $2\pi$ (call it $J_2$) vanish (the first vanish at rate $O(\frac{1}{n})$ and the second $O(e^{-2n\pi})$). Then I write:
$$I(n) = Re[\int_0^{2\pi} (1-s^2)^{-1} e^{-ns} ids]$$
Using Watson's lemma, I can easily show $I(n) = Re[i\sum_{m=0}^\infty \Gamma(2m+1)/n^{2m+1}] = 0 (*)$.
My question: I'm a bit unsure about my argument about showing the integral from 0 to $-2\pi i$ equal to the integral from 0 to $2\pi$, since what I've shown is that $J_{1,2} = 0$ but not, say, $J_{1,2} = o(I(n))$. Further, my result in $(*)$ is in odd powers of n, but the required form is in even powers, which made me suspicious about my answer. Could anyone verify this for me please?
Thank you!

Perhaps I miss something, but it seems $I(n)$ has infinitely many zeros all the way out to $n \to\infty$, so you can't truly have an asymptotic expansion in any power of $n$. Rather something like $I\sim\sin(2\pi n)\sum_k a_kn^{-k}+\cos(2\pi n)\sum_kb_kn^{-k}$ where the $a_k$ are zero for even $k$ and the $b_k$ are zero for odd $k$. Where is the question from?

Try calling $f(t) = (1+t^2)^{-1}$ and then use integration by parts with induction, if I'm not mistaken you will get something like $a_k = f^{(2k-1)}(2\pi)$

@Sal it's an exam question.

Integration by parts is the way to go. Some interesting reading for you: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.11#i

@RaulFernandesHorta thank you, you're absolutely right. I've made this overcomplicated. Integration by parts is doable since I only need to compute the first 3 coefficients. Thank you!

@Gary Thank you for the comment and extra reading :))

Don't use \Sigma for summations as they do not have the special formatting that \sum does.

Start with
$$\frac 1{1+t^2}=\frac 1{(t+i)(t-i)}=\frac i 2 \left(\frac{1}{t+i}-\frac{1}{t-i}\right)$$ Use obvious changes of variable, expand the trigonometir functions to obtain the antiderivative in terms of trigonometric functions and integrals
$$\color{blue}{I_n=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(nt)}{1+t^2}\,dt}$$ $$\color{red}{2\,I_n=(\text{Si}(n (i-2 \pi ))-\text{Si}(n (i+2 \pi ))) \sinh (n)+}$$ $$\color{red}{i (\text{Ci}(n (i+2 \pi ))-\text{Ci}(n (i-2 \pi ))) \cosh (n)}$$
Using the asymptotics
$$I_n=\frac{\pi }{2} e^{-n}-\frac{4 \pi }{\left(4 \pi ^2+1\right)^2}\frac 1 {n^2}+\frac{48 \pi  \left(4 \pi ^2-1\right)}{\left(4 \pi ^2+1\right)^4}\frac 1 {n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$
Tying for $n=10$ gives  $\color{red}{-5.16}41\times 10^{-6}$
Edit (for the fun)
$$I_n=\frac{\pi }{2} e^{-n}-\frac{4 \pi }{\left(4 \pi ^2+1\right)^2}\frac 1 {n^2}+\frac{48 \pi  \left(4 \pi ^2-1\right)}{\left(4 \pi ^2+1\right)^4}\frac 1 {n^4}-$$
$$\frac{480 \pi  \left(4 \pi ^2-3\right) \left(12 \pi
   ^2-1\right)}{\left(1+4 \pi ^2\right)^6 n^6}+$$ $$\frac{80640 \pi  (2 \pi -1) (1+2 \pi ) \left(-1-4 \pi +4 \pi
   ^2\right) \left(-1+4 \pi +4 \pi ^2\right)}{\left(1+4 \pi
   ^2\right)^8 n^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)$$
Tying for $n=10$ gives  $\color{red}{-5.165529}23\times 10^{-6}$
